# How to read DES encrypted file contents (Created with C#) on Android devices

Tags: c#, android, encryption, des

We have a bunch of contents which were already DES encrypted using C# on the desktop side. We want to decrypt them on the android application. Trying almost every encodings, we could not get the exact decrypted values on the android side. Could you please tell us what is wrong in android side? By the way, we know that DES is not the best solution for encryption. But, the contents were previously created and we have no option to use another mechanism.

**Here is the encryption code written with C#.**

```
using (FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(strOutputFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
    cryptic.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(passKey);
    cryptic.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(passKey);
    CryptoStream crStream = new CryptoStream(outputStream, cryptic.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    crStream.Write(fileBuffer, 0, fileBuffer.Length);
    crStream.Close();
}
```

**Here is the decryption part on the Android side**

```
String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "DES/CFB8/NoPadding";
SecretKeySpec key5= new SecretKeySpec("passkey*".getBytes("UTF-8"), 
    CIPHER_ALGORITHM);

String ivString = "passkey*";
byte[] ivByte = ivString.getBytes("UTF-8");
IvParameterSpec iv5 = new IvParameterSpec(ivByte);  

Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);
c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key5, iv5);

CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(
    new FileInputStream("/sdcard/test_folder/test.file"), c);

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cis));
Log.d("SONUC2", " " +br.readLine());
```

Comment: "*We could not get the exact decrypted values on the android side*" > Do you get errors? Do you get most of the correct values but some garbage at the beginning or the end?

Comment: **When we decrypt on the android application, the original value  does not match the decrypted value. Incorrect values are obtained**

Comment: Note: I've simplified your Java code to remove all the exception handling - we don't need to see that to understand what you're doing.

Comment: Your encryption code does not specify CFB8 or no padding.  Presumably it uses some C# default values.  You **must** check what those default values are and set the same values in Android.  CBC is more common that CFB8, and the presence of an IV may imply CBC as well.  No padding may give you garbage at the end of any decrypted chunk.

Answer (score 0):

"Thanks for your help. Changing the CIPHER_ALGORITHM to "DES/CBC/NoPadding solved my problem.